# I don't have a robot, can i use ROS with my desktop until i get one?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't yet have an expensive robot or the time to build one, but I do like the idea of having access via an API, both in allowing a robot access to my API data, but additionally this could provide something along the lines of shared "robot time" for folks that don't have a robot but would like to actually work with one.

Another thought on this topic would be using something like the API interface that benkehoe posted a few days ago.

If possible - could I use my desktop system in the mean time and prepare some programs or computer vision locally by using the ROS distro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134231/i-don%27t-have-a-robot,-can-i-use-ros-with-my-desktop-until-i-get-one?/) by [sixtyeightmk2](https://answers.ros.org/users/12581/sixtyeightmk2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simulate a robot in [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#ROS_Integration) and test your code on this robot.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-02-28**:
Somehow I missed this important feature when I was going through the ROS website and tutorials.  I wish this was clearer to newbies who install ROS and run through the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can simulate a robot in morse too. It is easy to use:

http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/latest/tutorials.html

---

Originally posted by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) with karma: 118 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1